# Switching between python3 interpreters in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythoninterpreter

I have been using python 34 and use pip from command line in windows to install my packages. Now I have installed python 36 without uninstalling python 34. However I cannot install packages into python 36 using pip as it is configured to Python 34. Any elegant solutions for this problem.

Comment: This should do the trick : py -3.6 -m pip install SomePackage

Comment: if my answer was the solution to this issue, would you please accept as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm adding my comment as an answer so I can add my reference.

use this command to specify which python version you want to install packages too. Just replace 'SomePackage' with the package name you want to install.

```
 py -3.6 -m pip install SomePackage
```

I found this on this [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html)

**EDIT**
This is for Windows. For Mac or Linux users switch `py -3.6` to `python3.6`